# Django comment spam

Tags: django, spam-prevention

How well does Django's anti-spam system in the comments framework work? Have you used it? What percentage of comment-spam does it prevent roughly? Is there anything else you do to help prevent comment spam on sites using the Django comments framework?

Comment: Are you having trouble reading the code?  http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/comments

Comment: No, but I'm not sure how looking at the code would tell me how well it works in the real world. Is there a particular bit of the code I should be looking at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Django only offers a honey pot field and a hash check for spam prevention. It stops a lot of spam but absolutely not all. I'd guess at maybe 50-70% or so. For a very small site I have with less than 50 unique visitors per day, that is all that is needed. For larger sites, you definitely need additional protection like Akismet.

Answer (score 5):

There's a Python API to [Askimet](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/akismet_python.html).  It's what wordpress uses to stop spam (and it works pretty well).