# Automatic spam filtering or flagging for Django or Python?

Tags: python, django, spam, spam-prevention

I'm working on a Django-based site that consists mostly of user- 
generated content: reviews, comments, tweet-like posts, etc.

I'm concerned about spam. Are there any spam filters available for 
Django/Python? If not, what types of algorithms can be used for automatic spam 
filtering or flagging?

On a more general note, does anyone know how do major sites like 
Amazon and Yelp prevent spams in their user-submitted reviews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [SO question 915204](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915204/django-comment-spam). [Jason Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2147/jason-baker) recommends using the [Akismet Python API](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/akismet%5Fpython.html), which he states is what WordPress uses to stop spam. From the [Akismet Python API](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/akismet%5Fpython.html) website:

> Akismet is a web service for recognising spam comments.

Also, Patrick Beeson has a [blog entry](http://patrickbeeson.com/blog/2009/feb/21/how-stop-spam-django-blog/) on how to use Akismet to stop spam on a Django blog that might be relevant to your application.

Answer (score 1):

[SpamBayes](http://spambayes.sourceforge.net/download.html) comes to mind.