# Django: Are the anti-spam measures in the comments framework sufficient? Or will I need to use a captcha or akismet?

Tags: django, spam-prevention

I'm going to be implementing the comments framework and I'm wondering what I should expect to run into. If someone could specifically explain the methods they've tried/tested for anti-spam measures in django and give recommendations I'd greatly appreciate it.

And yes, I have read some of the questions here but I haven't run into a detailed thorough answer specific to django.

Answer (score 2):

Disqus is built on Django, and we use a combination of Bayesian filtering (with a steady stream of ham and spam fed through our comments), rate and likeness limiting, selective captchas, and--at the user's discretion--akismet.

We're still fighting, as are all spam-susceptible web services, but those are some fairly common techniques.

Answer (score 1):

No there is'nt any working anti-spam in contrib comment framework.

1. use rate limit http://simonwillison.net/2009/Jan/7/ratelimitcache/
2. akismet http://books.google.com/books?id=rHGh5OihsCsC&lpg=PA129&ots=E9-0nmoWfA&dq=django%20spam%20analyzer&hl=pl&pg=PA129#v=onepage&q&f=false

I've tested honeypot, it stops 50% of spam. I've turned off retelimit and askimet on quite big page 100 comments per hour including 21 spam  (10 of them  have passed honneypot)

Comment: That's not true - there's honeypot stuff in there.

Comment: My mistake. I have only contrib comment framework in my mind.

Comment: @Dominic Rodger - but is it any useful?

Comment: @meder - that's an excellent question to which I've never received a satisfactory answer (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915204/django-comment-spam)

Comment: me too. The contrib comments framework does honeypot stuff (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/#notes-on-the-comment-form).

Answer (score 1):

It may be worthwhile to note that prolific Djangonaut Daniel Roseman [switched](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/04/21/bye-bye-djangocomments-hello-disqus/) his blog's comments system from Django's Comment app to [Disqus](http://disqus.com/) after facing "a flood of spam comments".

@Daniel is an user here; I'm sure he'll be along shortly to give you a more detailed answer.